# how to create private-public key pair for asymmetric cryptography using solidity

Tags: solidity

I will like to do federated learning on Ethereum. for this, I need to generate a private-public key pair for asymmetric cryptography for each global iteration. The private key will be used to decrypt the local model transactions send by mobile devices, while public key is shared to the devices for encrypting the local model transactions. I would like to do it using solidity.

Comment: I would also want to know any complications like privacy breach

Answer (score 0):

Solidity smart contracts are made for public transactions.

Generating your private key publicly does not make any sense.